Best practice with admin accounts and passwords
My team is responsible for a big ERP application. We have both developers and devops.
Sometimes we need to login to production and do "fixes". It can be to correct corrupt data, workaround for a bug etc. It is a complex system with active development.
So far we have one Admin account with a shared password. Most of us know the password.
My question is how can this be improved? What is best practice ?
The traceability is not good now. As we all use the same account we cannot see who did the changes from logs. So I suggest personal accounts instead.
But other disagree on this as it means instead of one admin account there will be many. I believe we are about six persons that need admin access.
Any advice ?

Shared passwords are bad for numerous reasons. They often evolve out of ignorance or insufficient ACL options in systems.
Ideally you want personal accountability and personal (admin) accounts that let users and admins alike do their jobs and when they switch roles or leave a job, you can revoke their personal account (or accounts) and they won’t have access anymore. Changing shared passwords is inconvenient and tends to never happen as nobody feels responsible for doing that.

I'm afraid this is opinion-based question, but I still find it useful and valuable so I'd like to throw my five cents.
I've always implemented the personal accounts. Strangely enough, this seemed to enhance overall security. It's not a widening of the attack surface, since all accounts are using the same machinery. Six admin accounts is no less worse in the "brute force" password breaking than a single account; monitoring and alerting for six accounts is no less harder that monitoring for a single account either. But this facilitates the use of dual factor authentication, because each admin can now use their own second factor independently. If someone is quitting, we can just lock their account, not bothering with updating shared password (better manageability); we can always know who was logged in during investigation (a better traceability you mentioned).
The shared passwords are only applicable in situations where there is no way to make personal accounts. I can identify two cases for this: either the system in question supports only a single account (think a managed network switch with only one password), or the licensing restrictions encourage to limit the number of non-production accounts (like Windows Server Foundation which allows for only 25 user accounts). In this case, it's advisable to use a shared secrets store, like Hashicorp Vault, and use scripting to automatically retrieve the password from the the store and send it to the system in question during authentication; this will ease the rotation of the password which now can be automated. The automatic rotation should be made quite frequent, to render the ignorant behavior like "copy password to own scratch to not access store every time" inefficient. In case of mentioned quitting of some person (or change in position), we just perform an extra rotation. Traceability is increased too, through the means of the shared secret store auditing.
Update: The HBruijn's comment is worth considering. If there was a shared password, we need to update it in case someone is quitting or changed role. If automatic rotation like I described wasn't implemented, it often doesn't happen at all, which is disaster for security. If some admin's password was leaked we at least can know whose and who to blame, but if the shared password was leaked, it's way too hard to point out how did it happen and secure the system so it doesn't happen anymore. If one of admins is malicious and if they are also smart, it would be almost impossible to track with a shared password. Overall, shared passwords are so bad for security so it overweights any perceived burden of managing several personal accounts.
